# how do I... comp/blur/depth of field an object so that it comes into view as the camera dollys?

Tags: compositing-nodes, blur, depth-of-field

Bad headline sorry,
here's a frog in a cage

[image]

the idea is, we first see froggy through the bars, which are so blurry we cant really figure them out.

[image]

as shown in this comp attempt ^above^ .because the most extreme depth of field just dont cut it -below-.

[image]

but using the current comp setup, when trying to blend the two layers together, I cant nicely merge them.
its sposed to look like pic 1 after the blur transition (and the camera pulls back)
[image]

so my next aattempt will be to animate froggy bouncing in his cage for a bit, duplicating him, making his duplicate vantablack and sending frog noir to the cage layer to act as a mask
and then blacking out everything behind the cage or just making its own alpha-relevant movie to put in top.

the next part of the animation is that the cage and frog interact in ways that make separate layers a pain. so i guess i'd make a duplicate cage and hide it out of sight until the blur transition finishes and then swap them over.

and maybe this will look good, but it will take days to find out (i'm slow).

also considering motion blur and using the graph editor modifiers to shake the shit outta the cage until the camera moves back, but..

anyone got an elegant solution?

Comment: Hey :). Why not just control the focus in camera during rendering? It'll give way better results than compositing.

Comment: Ya would be much easier, see pic 3 tho :(